# .net Core Newtonsoft.Json had 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I am developing on .net core 3.1 platform.

I use log4net for cross cutting concerns logging.
When I take any error from any service, It will convert to json object then write to log file.

I use .NET STANDARD library 2.1, this is code bellow

```
    var logEvent = new SerializableLogEvent(loggingEvent);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logEvent, Formatting.Indented); // problem is this line
    writer.WriteLine(json);
```

this SerializableLogEvent.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableLogEvent
{
    private LoggingEvent _loggingEvent;

    public SerializableLogEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        _loggingEvent = loggingEvent;
    }

    public object Message => _loggingEvent.MessageObject;
}
```

Why have it error ? System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

```
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
      HResult=0x80131604
      İleti=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
      Kaynak=System.Private.CoreLib
      StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<CreateSerializationCallback>b__0(Object o, StreamingContext context)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.InvokeOnSerializing(Object o, StreamingContext context)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.OnSerializing(JsonWriter writer, JsonContract contract, Object value)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting)
       at Core.CrossCuttingConcerns.Logging.Log4Net.Layouts.JsonLayout.Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent) in ...\Core\CrossCuttingConcerns\Logging\Log4Net\Layouts\JsonLayout.cs:line 21
       at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.RenderLoggingEvent(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
       at log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
       at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
       at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    
    
    
    PlatformNotSupportedException: This instance contains state that cannot be serialized and deserialized on this platform.
```

Comment: It would appear that something in `SerializableLogEvent` is not serializable on the platform you're developing on, as per the last line of the exception.

log4net has been dormant for a while and is no longer supported, so rather than invest time in trying to get it to work, it might be better to migrate to a supported alternative.

Comment: @MartinCostello which one is alternative for log4net ?

Comment: In the class SerializableLogEvent define a function that retun a strin or json string ,that should call and return value stored in LogEvent not the object of the class ,

Comment: @CodAvo there are many alternatives, such as Serilog and NLog. You'll have to do your own research into what would be a supported alternative for your use case.

Comment: Json.NET is throwing an exception trying to invoke an [`[OnSerializing]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback.  `SerializableLoggingEvent` has no such callback, so it must be applied to the `object Message`.  So, what is `Message`?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: What is your `loggingEvent`?Did you add NewtonSoft support like below:`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`?

Comment: @Rena services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(), I try this one but this extensions not found new .net core 3.1 version, I think

Comment: You need first Install-Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`.Then you could add `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()`.

Comment: @Rena, the problem still persist.